# Getting table rownum?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get table row number that clicked.
Table has id only on table-body, not table, tr and td

Question :

How can I get the row number I clicked?

```
test.prototype.clickRowDisplay = function () {

//code

};
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This help you :

```
$("table tr").on("click",function(index){
    alert("You Click Number : " + ($(this).index() + 1));
  })
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>Ehsan</td><td>Taghdisi</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Amin</td><td>Abbas</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Saeed</td><td>Hassani</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Karim</td><td>kazem</td></tr>
        </table>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("table tr").on("click",function(index){
                    alert("You Click Number : " + ($(this).index() + 1));
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

It will return you the row number of tr which is clicked

Comment: First, thx for answer. But I just want to use this logic without .click form. I want to make the function that letting me know the num of table body row.

Answer (score 0):

This would get you the index of the clicked row. The code is as below.

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

If you want to return the number stored in that first cell of each row. Then the code for it is as shown below:

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
  var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  alert('You clicked ' + row);
});
```